# Lightning bug after joining meshes

Tags: light, error

I have been working on a festival lantern for some hours and i had some different meshes in the blender project. Because i was going to use this in my unreal engine 4 project i had to join them together but after i selected every mesh and clicked on join, the mesh turned dark. In Unreal Engine its looking weird and the mesh is only rendering from one side.

[image: Before i joined the meshes..]

**Before** i joined the meshes

[image: After i joined the meshes.]

**After** i joined the meshes.

[image: In Unreal Engine 4]

**In** Unreal engine 4 (The part above the lantern is not correctly rendered.)

Could somebody help me solving this problem?

Comment: Sorry about bad english, im from germany...

Comment: Have you recalculated normals after joining the objects? (in Edit Mode select the whole mesh with *A*, then press *Ctrl+N*).

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you tell a bit more about the modifers that each object owned before and after?

Comment: And how do i fix this? @Sazerac

Comment: And by the way, @Neberich, your English is just fine. I've seen far worse in other posts. (: